# iOS Enterprise Distribution for multiple clients

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

Hope you all had a good weekend.

We're just about to sign up to the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) but I've got a couple of questions before we do so.

1. We're a solutions provider and will be developing many apps for our own clients, mostly Enterprise ones. Does every client need to sign up for this program or can we distribute on behalf of everyone?
2. Do devices still need to be provisioned (i.e. do we have to register their UDIDs) in order to distribute the app, or can we simply put it behind a secured webpage and anyone with a user/pass can download them?

My guess is that only WE have to sign up for the dev programme and that once we have an Enterprise account we will no longer need device UDIDs and can share to just about anyone, but I'd like to be 100% certain.

I appreciate any insight you may be able to provide.
Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Marko, we are also planning to sign up for enterprise program for iOS developer. Can you please tell me how would I exactly distribute the App? What's the difference between Ad-hoc distribution and Enterprise? I know ad-hoc distribution and we have been using it since long now. Is Enterprise program able to distribute apps automatically to all devices? Don't I need to provision using UDIDs? Thanks for your any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your license will only allow you to distribute to your own staff and devices.  It explicitly prohibits you from installing on client's devices.  Therefore you will have to have your clients set up their own Enterprise accounts and you will have to build the app using their permissions.
2. You do not need UDID's.  You can distribute to any device.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there any other option we have for the distribution apart from the App Store? Getting each company registered with a DUNS number and an Enterprise account seems like quite a bit of work.

Comment: No that I know of. My company has had some similar challenges.  I don't know exactly what you guys are delivering but you might be able to do something where you lease the hardware to them so it's technically yours.

Comment: "Your license will only allow you to distribute to your own staff and devices. It explicitly prohibits you from installing on client's devices." - You have any reference for that?

Comment: @cschuff This is 3 years later but I was looking for the same info and found it: `"'I am a contractor who wants to create an in-house app for my client. Can I join the iOS Developer Enterprise Program to do that?' No. The iOS Developer Enterprise Program is for companies/organizations to develop and distribute proprietary in-house apps to their employees. Your client should enroll in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program and add the appropriate developers from your company to their iOS Development Team."` https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html

Answer (score -1):

You only need to register, you can sign them to use the app, iOS Developer Enterprise does not need to provide udid, just set up trust. I Give you this app